# How to create a npm package from a package with multiple workspaces?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a npm package that has multiple workspaces.

The code structure is as follows:

- project

  - workspace-1

    - package.json
  - workspace-2

    - package.json
  - package.json

And my `project/package.json` is:

```json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "workspaces": [
    "workspace-1",
    "workspace-2"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I run `npm pack` on the project folder and install it on another project, the package is installed, but none of the dependencies of the workspaces are.

I end with an node_modules almost empty:

- other_project

  - node_modules

    - .bin
    - package

It fails to run because the needed dependencies are not installed. Do you know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

I've tried installing with `npm pack -ws` but it installs 2 different packages, one for each workspace, and that's not what I wanted. I wanted 1 package with the other 2 inside.

Comment: The dependencies that one of your workspaces needs when installed should be in _its_ package file. They'll be installed in the root modules directory and listed in the root lock file.

Comment: Yes, the dependencies for workspace-1 are in workspace-1/package.json, and they're installed in the root node_modules and are in the root package-lock.json, but that doesn't exist in the pack version. It's like the pack ignores the package.json of the workspaces and doesn't read its dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I've found a solution. My workspaces weren't a dependency of the main package so I've added this to the project/package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "workspace-1" : "file:./workspace-1",
  "workspace-2" : "file:./workspace-2"
},
```

This solved the problem but now my code is duplicated in the node-modules when I install it